# How can an affine transformation preserve parallelism if it includes an arbitrary nonsingular linear transformation?

Tags: geometry, soft-question, affine-geometry

How can an affine transformation preserve parallelism if it includes an arbitrary nonsingular linear transformation?

Let $A_0$ be a vector, $T$ a nonsingular linear transformation and define an affine transformation of some affine space by $$A \rightarrow A_0 + TA$$

Affine transofmrations are known to preserve parallelism. But how can this be when nonsingular linear transformations need not preserve parallelism? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you can explain how a nonsingular linear transformation would fail to preserve parallelism?  I can see why they don't preserve  *orthogonality* in general.

Comment: Ah, nevermind!! haha.